# Is nextLine method in java.util.Scanner package take string from user?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, string-matching

I was trying to compare a user input with a predefined string. But it did not show my expected result. Here is the code

```html
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StringMatching {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scannerObj=new Scanner(System.in);
        String userinput=scannerObj.nextLine();
            System.out.println(userinput);

        System.out.println(userinput);
        if(userinput=="yes")
        {
            System.out.println("Yes! Working..");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Working..");
        }


    }
}
```

The output of this program shows **Not Working**.
I don't know what I missed here. Looking for your kind support.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

In Java == compares whether the two references refers to the same object. It does not check whether the content of the string is equal.

As already stated, use String.equals(otherString) instead